# Connection timeout after 30 seconds

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a C# program connecting to a MYSQL database. The stored procedure takes longer than 30 seconds so the connection times out. What I'm looking to do is to increase the alloted time to do the stored procedure to 5 minutes. I know that the default time out is 30 seconds and need to increase the alloted time. Is it possible to do this in C# or do I need to perform less stored procedures?

Answer (score 2):

You can also configure your timeout in your string connection by using `Connect Timeout property`

```
Config File : "Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Connect Timeout=...."
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using "Command Timeout=300" in the connection string.

Comment: I'am happy to help you user2132252

Answer (score 0):

Where you create your sql query command:

```
command.CommandTimeout = int.MaxValue;
```

or set int.MaxValue to the timeout of your choice.